# Salesforce SOQL Query to Retrieve Users that Downloaded Content

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to run some analysis on which users have downloaded specific content objects.  On the UI, I can see who(and when) it was downloaded.  Does anyone know what object I can query using SOQL to see when User X downloaded Document Y.

Thanks

Comment: They are either Attachments (with a parent object) or Documents (with no parent), I'd suggest starting with the web services API doc and it's datamodel section - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_documents.htm - unfortunately it doesn't tell you what you need to know, but might offer some pointers.

Comment: Are you talking about CRM Content or the standard Attachments & Documents as per David Gillen above?

Answer (score 2):

Content downloads are stored in the ContentVersionHistory object.  If you wanted to query when user x downloaded document y, where x is User.Id, y is ContentVersion.Id, then this code will get you there:

```
DateTime mostRecentDownloadDateTime;
Id downloadedById = '00550000001NLJsAAO';
Id contentVersionId = '068P000000005ck'; 
List<ContentVersionHistory> mostRecentDownload = 
[select createdDate, field from ContentVersionHistory 
 where createdById = :downloadedById 
 and contentVersionId = :contentVersionId 
 and field = 'contentVersionDownloaded'
 order by createdDate desc
 limit 1];
if(!mostRecentDownload.isEmpty())
 mostRecentDownloadDateTime = mostRecentDownload.get(0).createdDate;
```

Be careful of the difference between content version and content document.  Depending on your specific use case you may care about one over the other.

For full details check out the Content ERD and the Content Objects in the Salesforce Webservices API.
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contentversionhistory.htm
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_content.htm